# sqlite3 explain table_name

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

In mysql you can view a table's structure via `explain tablename;` What is the equivalent for sqlite3?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305378/get-list-of-tables-db-schema-dump-etc-in-python-sqlite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe ".schema tablename" is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.schema` in the [Command Line Shell](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html):

> With no arguments, the ".schema"
>   command shows the original CREATE
>   TABLE and CREATE INDEX statements that
>   were used to build the current
>   database. If you give the name of a
>   table to ".schema", it shows the
>   original CREATE statement used to make
>   that table and all if its indices.

Answer (score 2):

This was already answered in a more generic way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305378/get-list-of-tables-db-schema-dump-etc-in-python-sqlite3/305639#305639).

**Edit**:

Note that `.schema` will also give you INDEXES that match the same name.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE job (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    data VARCHAR
);
CREATE TABLE job_name (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR
);
CREATE INDEX job_idx on job(data);
```

Note the differences between:

```
sqlite> SELECT sql FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'job';
CREATE TABLE job (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        data VARCHAR
    )
sqlite> SELECT sql FROM SQLITE_MASTER WHERE name = 'job_idx';
CREATE INDEX job_idx on job(data)
```

and

```
sqlite> .schema job
CREATE TABLE job (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        data VARCHAR
    );
CREATE INDEX job_idx on job(data);
```

Including the *semi-colon* at the end of the queries.

Comment: It was indeed. My question is a little more specific though.