# Need regex expression to get only Tably name and primary key in python

Tags: python, regex

May this question is silly, but i am not able to generate the regex expression to fetch table Name and PRIMARY KEY.

### TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE 'dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface'  (
        'vrId' integer default 0,
        'ifName' string ,
        PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId),
        FOREIGN KEY (vrId) REFERENCES 'vr_vr'(vrId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

I am using: 
`begin = re.compile(r"CREATE TABLE[ \"]*([^ \"]+)[ \"]*[(]([^/;]+)[/;]",re.IGNORECASE)` to fetch all table name and data.

But i would need data only with table name and PRIMARY KEY.

**Expected Output:**

```
dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface
PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following was tested using python2.7:

```
>>> table_string = """
... CREATE TABLE 'dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface'  (
...         'vrId' integer default 0,
...         'ifName' string ,
...         PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId),
...         FOREIGN KEY (vrId) REFERENCES 'vr_vr'(vrId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCAD
E);"""
>>> p = r'CREATE TABLE\s+\'([^\']+)[\s\S]+PRIMARY KEY\(([^,]+),([^\)]+)\)'
>>> re.findall(p,table_string)
[('dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface', 'ifName', 'vrId')]
```

The explanation can be found [here.](https://regex101.com/r/nJ7yW3/1)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to get the output using re.search() operation

Comment: @rishinarian: Yes.  `re.search` will scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning a match object, or None if no match was found. So, you can do `m = re.search(p,table_string)`, then `print [m.group(i+1) for i in range(3)]`. The output is: `['dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface', 'ifName', 'vrId']`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution takes care of some issues you seem not worried about (but which are good to worry about), e.g., SQLite allows you to write escaped `'` as `''`, and there may be any number of spaces, even newlines, between `CREATE` and `TABLE`, and between `PRIMARY`, `KEY`, and `(`:

```
s = """\
CREATE TABLE 'dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface'  (
    'vrId' integer default 0,
    'ifName' string ,
    PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId),
    FOREIGN KEY (vrId) REFERENCES 'vr_vr'(vrId)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
"""

pattern = """
    CREATE \s+ TABLE \s+
    '((?:[^']|'')*)'      # allows escaped single quote
    .+                    # stuff between table name and primary key
    (PRIMARY \s+ KEY\s? \([^)]*\))
"""
mo = re.search(pattern, s, re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)
print(mo.groups())
```

Output:

```
('dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface', 'PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId)')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can solve it with regular expressions or [`sqlparse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse), but here is a "fun" way of approaching the problem just for educational purposes - using [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) *in memory* database - actually create the table and get the `table_name` from the [`sqlite_master` internal table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746045/771848) and primary key columns from the [`PRAGMA table_info`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info):

```
import sqlite3

query = """
CREATE TABLE 'dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface'  (
        'vrId' integer default 0,
        'ifName' string ,
        PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId),
        FOREIGN KEY (vrId) REFERENCES 'vr_vr'(vrId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
"""

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute(query)
db.commit()

# get table name
cursor.execute("select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'")
table_name = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print(table_name)

# get primary key columns
cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info(%s);" % table_name)
pk_columns = [row[1] for row in cursor.fetchall()[::-1]]
print(pk_columns)
```

Prints:

```
dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface
['ifName', 'vrId']
```

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. Can you please provide regrex expression if u have idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to just get the table name and primary key.

```
begin = re.compile(r"CREATE TABLE[ ']*([^ ']+)[ ']*[(][^/;]+(PRIMARY KEY.*),[^/;]+;$", re.IGNORECASE)
begin.findall(YOUR_STR)
```

Outputs:

```
In [1]: a = """CREATE TABLE 'dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface'  (
...:         'vrId' integer default 0,
...:         'ifName' string ,
...:         PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId),
...:         FOREIGN KEY (vrId) REFERENCES 'vr_vr'(vrId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON
UPDATE CASCADE);"""
In [2]: begin = re.compile(r"CREATE TABLE[ ']*([^ ']+)[ ']*[(][^/;]+(PRIMARY KEY.*),[^/;]+;$", re.IGNORECASE)
In [3]: begin.findall(a)
Out[3]: [('dhcpr_dhcprelayinterface', 'PRIMARY KEY(ifName,vrId)')]
```

Comment: I tried with the above expression it is not working.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to print the data, using begin.search(a) instead of findall()

Comment: Yes, use ````match = begin.search(a)```` and this returns a match object and you get your data using ````match.groups()````

Comment: I have the variable a that you are using as a really big string of SQL statements. I used the rest of the code exactly how it is but didn't work for me at all. I got nothing returned.