# How to print tablename and primary key from file.sql in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a requirement to print tablename and primary key using the below program. But it is not working. Could you please help in solving this.
I have used the regex pattern to find out table name and PRIMARY KEY data in the database Schema.

```
class ParseCreateFile:

    begin = re.compile(r"CREATE \s+ TABLE \s+'((?:[^']|'')*)'.+(PRIMARY \s+ KEY\s? \([^)]*\))", re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)

    def __init__(self,fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.readFromFile()

    def readFromFile(self):
        try:
            file = open(self.fileName,'r')
            fileData = file.read()
            file.close()
            self.parse(fileData)
        except IOError:
            print 'Unable to read file %s' % self.fileName

    def parse(self,rawData):
        self.list = []
        while rawData:
          mo = self.begin.search(rawData)
          tablename, fil = mo.groups()
          print tablename, fil
          if mo is None:
            break
          rawData = rawData[mo.end():]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "only the main classes"
        file = ParseCreateFile('file2.sql')
```

### file2.sql

```
CREATE TABLE 'x'(
  'X' integer
  PRIMARY KEY(dn)
  'Y' short);
CREATE TABLE 'y'(
  'X1' integer
  PRIMARY KEY(dn1, dn2)
  'Y1' short);

Expected Out:
x: PRIMARY KEY(dn)
y: PRIMARY KEY(dn1, dn2)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need regex expression to get only Tably name and primary key in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35617396/need-regex-expression-to-get-only-tably-name-and-primary-key-in-python)

Comment: With simple string, things are working fine. But the same is not working when i am trying with the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the regex, and used the findall.

```
class ParseCreateFile:

    begin = re.compile(r"CREATE TABLE[ ']*([^ ']+)[ ']*[(][^/;]+(PRIMARY KEY.*)[^/;]+;", re.IGNORECASE)

    def __init__(self,fileName):
        self.fileName = fileName
        self.readFromFile()

    def readFromFile(self):
        try:
            file = open(self.fileName,'r')
            fileData = file.read()
            file.close()
            self.parse(fileData)
        except IOError:
            print 'Unable to read file %s' % self.fileName

    def parse(self,rawData):
        self.list = []
        found = self.begin.findall(rawData)
        for i in found:
            print i[0], i[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "only the main classes"
    file = ParseCreateFile('file2.sql')
```

Comment: With the above program, the output is shown as "only the main classes". It is not working. The desired output is not shown.

Comment: Removed ````re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL````

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Hi Akram,  if i have tables like this CREATE TABLE 'x'(
  'X' integer
  PRIMARY KEY(dn));
CREATE TABLE 'y'(
  'X1' integer
  PRIMARY KEY(dn1, dn2));  The above logic doesn't work

Comment: Hopefully this will work for everything you had till now, you need to fix the regex. ````re.compile(r"CREATE TABLE[ ']*([^ ']+)[ ']*[(][^/;]+(PRIMARY KEY.*?\))[^/;]+;", re.IGNORECASE)````

Comment: Thanks for the answer