# Python SQLite equivalent to .tables (one-liner without Pandas)

Tags: python, sqlite

When using the SQLite executable, I can print to console a list of all the tables in a database with `.tables`. Is there an equivalent one-liner way to do this in Python using the sqlite3 module without using Pandas?

Based on the answers at [List of tables, db schema, dump etc using the Python sqlite3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305378/list-of-tables-db-schema-dump-etc-using-the-python-sqlite3-api), it appears you have to create a cursor first, then a SQL query to return a list of the tables (which is actually a list of tuples as unicode characters that needs to be cleaned for a pretty print to console). That's five lines, versus SQLite's one line.

Or maybe a related question is: why do I need to open a cursor to get this information in Python sqlite3?

```
con = sqlite3.connect(db)

cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
tables = cursor.fetchall()
tables = map(str, [t[0] for t in tables])
print(tables)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but since you're only using the variables once, you can simply chain all the calls.

```
print([str(t[0]) for t in sqlite3.connect(db).cursor().execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'").fetchall()])
```

Comment: in other words, there is no way to pass SQLite's `.tables` helper function inside Python?

Comment: That was already answered in the question you linked to.

Comment: I did not see that explicitly stated, I must have overlooked someone's answer?

Comment: But surely if there were such a simple way to do it, someone would have posted it.

Comment: lol you'd think, but judging by the question and the accepted answer, I have no idea what people think