# How to get list of all the tables in sqlite programmatically

Tags: sqlite

How can I get the list of all the available tables in sqlite programmatically?

Comment: @MaheshBabu: Jhaliya's answer is correct according to me. So please try that out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list the tables in an SQLite database file that was opened with ATTACH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-to-list-the-tables-in-an-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table';
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the below sql statement to get list of all table in sqllite data base

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

The same question asked before on StackOverFlow.

[How to list the tables in an SQLite database file that was opened with ATTACH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file)

Comment: +1 for your answer because you have even provided the link in case it is not clear. :-)

Answer (score 3):

worked for me

```
    SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table'
```

Answer (score 1):

To get only the names of the table run the below query.

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

Running the above query on `Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite` produce the following output:

```
sqlite> SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
Album
Artist
Customer
Employee
Genre
Invoice
InvoiceLine
MediaType
Playlist
PlaylistTrack
Track
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('''
    SELECT tbl_name
    FROM sqlite_master
    WHERE type = 'table';
''')

print(cur.fetchall())
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?