# List tables of sqlite database in chrome extension?

Tags: android-sqlite

I'm using sqlite manager extension in chrome to use sqlite database.I have a sqlite database.This extension works properly with select delete alter commands.but the problem is i can't list tables of database.is there any way to do this?.

Comment: You should search SO before posting a question. This question had been asked and answered a number of time already. Two examples: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334882/how-to-get-list-of-all-the-tables-in-sqlite-programmatically) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-to-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not said what extension you are running for SO members to be able to offer definitive help.

Having said that, if you say can run SELECT queries, try:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

If you want **only the table name**, without schema details, try:

```
SELECT name  FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

**Examples, including table creation**

```
/* Create 3  table */
CREATE TABLE Your_First_Table (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Address text);
CREATE TABLE Your_Second_Table (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Price text);
CREATE TABLE Your_third_Table (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Stats text);

/*Get table names and schema details */
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';

/*Get table names */
SELECT name  FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

**Output from 1st Select:**

```
table|Your_First_Table|Your_First_Table|2|CREATE TABLE Your_First_Table (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Address text)
table|Your_Second_Table|Your_Second_Table|3|CREATE TABLE Your_Second_Table (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Price text)
table|Your_third_Table|Your_third_Table|4|CREATE TABLE Your_third_Table (Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Stats text)
```

**Output from 2nd Select:**

```
Your_First_Table
Your_Second_Table
Your_third_Table
```