# python with sqlite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite, command

For now I am trying to use python for sqlite3. My question is, I don't know how to read the existed 'abc.db' with python.
I mean that I just know the abc.db is a sqlite3 file. But I don't know the structure of it, and I also need to get the information from this abc.db.

I used :

```
import sqlite3
try:  
        sqlite_conn = sqlite3.connect('abc')  
except sqlite3.Error, e:  
         print 'conntect sqlite database failed.'  
         sqlite_logger.error("conntect sqlite database failed, ret = %s" % e.args[0])
```

So, what can I do next? I need to read the abc, and if it is possible, I want to output the content directly on the terminal. Is it possible? Because I need to analyse the data in this file. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list the tables in a SQLite database file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file)

Comment: RE: "output the content directly to the terminal" : sqlite3 has a ".dump" command which you can use to have it spit out SQL that would recreate the current state of the database.  This is essentially a backup mechanism, but allows you to see what is in the database in painful detail.  You can pass a ".dump" to the database with a python connection -- you don't necessarily need to use the commandline sqlite3 binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sqlite_conn object you could run the following command

```
cur = sqlite_conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print row[0]
```

Then you could do a `SELECT * from <Tablename>` for each of those tables.  The sqlite_master is a sqlite metadata here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command-line sqlite3 client, you can see the schema of an unknown db using:

```
.schema
```

then poke around a bit with SQL to get a better idea of the data within.