# Is there any way to check the presence and the structure of tables in a SQLite3 database?

Tags: sqlite

I'm developing [a Rust application for user registration via SSH](https://github.com/boringplace/borsh/pull/5) (like the one working for SDF).

I'm using the SQLite3 database as a backend to store the information about users.

I'm opening the database file (or creating it if it does not exist) but I don't know the approach for checking if the necessary tables with expected structure are present in the database.

I tried to use `PRAGMA schema_version` for versioning purposes, but this approach is unreliable.

I found that there are posts with answers that are heavily related to my question:

- [How to list the tables in a SQLite database file that was opened with ATTACH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-to-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach)
- [How do I retrieve all the tables from database? (Android, SQLite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572144/how-do-i-retrieve-all-the-tables-from-database-android-sqlite)
- [How do I check in SQLite whether a table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists)

Comment: The usual way is to use the `application_id` and `user_version` pragmas and create tables etc. if they're not set to appropriate numbers.

Comment: No worries. You can see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53731610/revisions) for every post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm opening the database file (or creating it if it does not exist)
>   but I don't know the approach for checking if the necessary tables

I found querying **sqlite_master** to check for tables, indexes, triggers and views and for columns using **`PRAGMA table_info(the_table_name)`** to check for columns.

e.g. the following would allow you to get the core basic information and to then be able to process it with relative ease (just for tables for demonstration):-

```
SELECT name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name LIKE 'my%';
```

> with expected structure

```
PRAGMA table_info(mytable);
```

The first results in (for example) :-

[image]

Whilst the second results in (for mytable) :-

[image]

- Note that type is blank/null for all columns as the SQL to create the table doesn't specify column types.

If you are using SQLite 3.16.0 or greater then you could use [PRAGMA Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) (e.g. pragma_table_info(table_name)) rather than the two step approach need prior to 3.16.0.

Comment: Wow! You've performed a nice investigation. Much better than related answers.