# Loop SQLite query for many databases in one directory to sort positive hits (UNIX)

Tags: sqlite, unix, loops

I have a directory with lots and lots of SQLite database files.

I need to run an sqlite3 query to establish if any database in my directory contains a specific table. Database filenames go like 001.db, 002.db, etc. If a database contains the table I require, the file is copied to a different directory.

My initial thoughts are similar to this:

> while [ sqlite3 $* "SELECT * FROM table1" != "Error: no such
>   table: table1" ]`
>
> do
>
> cp $* newdir/
>
> done

or something similar, and I need some help with correct syntaxis please...

in "$*" I meant a database file currently being processed inside the directory, not sure if it is correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to do a select in a table to see if it exists. You could [run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file) something like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

or adapt it to do a count:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM dbname.sqlite_master WHERE type='table' and name='table_name';
```

Using the sqlite command line, you should get a "1" or a "0". You can use that in figuring out if the DB actually has your desired table or not and act accordingly. The script could look something like:

```
for i in `ls *.db`; do
    HAS_TABLE=`sqlite "${i}" "select count(*) ....;"
    if [[ ${HAS_TABLE} == "1" ]]; then
      cp ${i} some/other/dir/${i}
    fi
done
```

I'm writing this from memory, so the syntax of the if/condition may be off a bit (you might be ok without the quotes around the `1` value).

HTH,

Comment: Thank you. I'm mainly concerned with performing a loop over the command to copy databases with positive hits to a new directory.