# Extract tables from sql expression

Tags: c, macos, sqlite

I'm try get name of tables in sql expression using `sqlite3 API`.

Example:

```
select * form table1, table2, table3;
```

Sqlite3 API only return data of statment and only have information of name of columns with command `sqlite3_column_name` but not have information of tables.

I need extract this:

```
table1
table2
table3
```

Comment: To find this using gxxgle it took me 5 seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/q/82875/694576

Comment: @alk I need to extract it from the sql expression and not from schema database.

Comment: Doesn't your code build the expression? Are you looking for an SQL parser though?

Comment: @alk No. The expression is write by user. Yes this is what I want but believed the `Sqlite API` provide a way to return this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table name of a returned column, call [sqlite3_column_table_name](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_database_name.html).
(This works only for actual table columns, not for expressions.)

To detect which tables are actually read by a statement, install an [authorizer callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html).

Comment: Xcode compilation return error `"_sqlite3_column_table_name", referenced from: ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. This function included in OSX? Other functions `sqlite3_column_origin_name` and `sqlite3_column_database_name` appear the same error.

Comment: See the documentation: "These APIs are only available if the library was compiled with the SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA C-preprocessor symbol."

Comment: I need include `sqlite-amalgamation` in my project to see these functions.