# How to get table names in sqllite database

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I am using cordova + angular js for developing the mobile app. For creating this POC I am using this [SQL tutorial](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/use-sqlite-instead-local-storage-ionic-framework/). Now I want to fetch tables name from sqllite db. for this I write below code.

```
        vm.tableName = function(){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=?";
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, ['table']).then(function(res) {
            alert("res "+JSON.stringify(res));
        }, function (err) {
            alert("err "+JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }
```

I can successfully read and write data in db, but I can't fetch the table names. I think, I miss something, but  I get related answer but it not work for me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file). And I don't understand how to attach db. I get some response from db when I run the above code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use this query for fetch all the tables from database. `SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table';`. It works for both android and ios but in android it gives one extra table "android_metadata". for this I use below code

```
for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
    if (res.rows.item(i).tbl_name !== "android_metadata") 
       ARRAYNAME.push(res.rows.item(i).tbl_name);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

Above Query should return following columns

[image]