# How to list all table names contained in telephony.db in android programmatically

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried to get the table names from android mobile programmatically using the following code:

```
Cursor tableCursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://telephony/sqlite_master"),new String[]{"name"}, "type='table'", null,null);
```

but I am getting tableCursor as `null` .So can anyone help me out of this

```
android.provider.telephony.db is the default database in android mobile.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may Help You, Visit here
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file

Comment: @maven:Thank you for your response, but I have seen these example they are given in queries, but i want them programmatically in android.

Comment: once you have this Result, you can Loop over it and get all these Tables.

Comment: @HP's 411: I did not understand your answer.My question is if I develop a program in android and install in my mobile i have to see all the table names that are present in my mobile's telephony.db

Comment: see this > https://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/android-how-to-poke-around-the-sqlite3-databases/