# Show Tables in SQLite Database in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I know this is a very basic question but for some reason I can't get past this one error. I'm trying to show/put all the names of the tables in a database (named 'GData.db') into a variable `available_tables` in Python. Currently I have the following:

```
con = sql.connect(r'/Users/linnk/Desktop/Results/GData.db')
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute("SHOW TABLES IN GData")
available_table=(cursor.fetchall())
```

This gives me the following error for the second-last line:

```
OperationalError: near "SHOW": syntax error
```

I've looked at the SHOW TABLES documentation as well as around the web but not found information that helps me.

Comment: *What* "SHOW TABLES documentation"? There isn't any, because SHOW TABLES is a MySQL-specific extension and doesn't exist in sqlite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list the tables in a SQLite database file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-do-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file)

Comment: This documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html
Also - to Peter Wood - I looked at that question but it didn't help me figure this out.

Comment: @LinnK `sqlite` and `mysql` are two different databases.

Comment: Yes, did figure that out:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The query to list tables in a Sqlite database:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name;
```

So your snippet becomes:

```
con = sql.connect(r'/Users/linnk/Desktop/Results/GData.db')
mycur = con.cursor() 
mycur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name;")
available_table=(mycur.fetchall())
```

See the [Sqlite FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! I skipped the ORDER BY part, but otherwise perfect.