# SQLite in memory from jar resource

Tags: java, sqlite

I want to use SQLite in memory mode, and load a DB file that is stored inside the jar. Seems like SQLite can't find/load the file. Here's my code:

```
String dbpath = Resources.getResource("my-db.dat").getPath();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
File dbfile = new File(dbPath);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
try {
    statement.executeUpdate("restore from " + dbfile.getPath());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error re-constructing in memory data base from Db file.");
}
```

The code isn't failing during restore, but when I try to query the DB I'm getting an error (`org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: my_table)`).

Things do work in regular mode (not in-memory).

Comment: Please post complete LogCat.

Comment: It's not an android app

Comment: A embedded resource can't be referenced as a File, because it's not, it's a entry in a Zip file, you'll probably need to extract it to temp file. You can use Class#getResourceAsStream to get an InputStream to the resource

Comment: @danieln alright, post the full error message.

Comment: @danieln and it is possible that the table isn't there. Try checking what the names are - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-to-list-the-tables-in-an-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach

Comment: @Sufian, it is there as it is working in non in-memory mode.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, things do work in non in-memory mode, without extracting the file.

Comment: I'm sure they do, I wasn't talking about the db, I was talking about the restore file, which I assume the by its nature, the restore command wants a reference to an actual file

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer, that's the pose I used as a reference for *non* in-memory mode, and things were working great.

Comment: In the disk case, the driver has specific support for hooking up sqlite with the data from the jar. The driver takes the resource as a parameter. In the memory case, you're asking sqlite itself to somehow find a file that isn't actually a file. That isn't going to work. The code you've posted doesn't work as is for an on-disk db either does it? If give it a restore statement with a path to something that's actually inside the jar, does that work? I'm guessing no.

Comment: Unless you use some kind of script instead, i guess you're stuck with a temp file

Comment: Also, is the performance difference really going to matter that much to you? For a small file that will effectively end up in memory anyway, it's probably going to be roughly the same, minus the hassle of extracting anything.

Comment: @pvg that's assuming the OP only wants a read-only connection, rather than being able to write to a temporary database that's initialized from the resource

Comment: I just need to read from the DB.

Comment: One convoluted option is to keep a sql statement level db dump in your jar. You can then read it to populate an in-memory sqlite db. This gives you an in-memory db at the cost of: more complicated code, longer startup/init time and a more annoying process whenever you need to update the embedded data.

Comment: @danieln if you just want to read it, what's the advantage of restoring from the resource into an in-memory database, over simply connecting directly to the read-only database inside the jar using `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::" + dbPath)`?