# Display all the tables in the current database using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

How can I display display all the tables in the current database using sql? Right now I'm just trying to count the number of tables in the database but what I'd like to do is list out all of the table names and write them to a new list.

```
public void UpdateListData(string driftID)
    {
        // string sql = "SELECT * FROM \"" + driftID + "\" ";
        // GameManager.Drift = dbManager.Query<Drift>(sql);    // Write Query to List

        string dbName = dbManager.workingName;
        Debug.Log(dbManager.workingName);

        string sql = "SELECT name FROM Drifts.sqlite WHERE type = 'table'";
        GameManager.Drifts.Add(dbManager.Query<Drift>(sql));

        foreach (List<Drift> drift in GameManager.Drifts)
        {
            numDriftSets++;
        }

        Debug.Log("There are " + numDriftSets + "drift sets in the list.");

        // Debug.Log("The current item count is : " + GameManager.Drift.Count);
        // Debug.Log("LIST TEST : " + GameManager.Drift[1].DriftStep);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-to-list-the-tables-in-an-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach