# Why isn't the table logins meta found but the file exists?

Tags: c, sqlite

I am trying to access the data that is saved by google chrome, I can read the file but for some reason I am unable to execute the statement `select * from meta`

Here is the code I am using to do so

```
    sqlite3 * db; 
    char path[] = "C:\\Users\\mike\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data";
    char pass_query[] = "select * from meta";



    int rc = sqlite3_open(path, &db);
    printf(BCYN "sqlite3_open returned: " BRED" %d \n" reset , rc);


    sqlite3_stmt * pStmt; 
    int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, pass_query, -1, &pStmt, 0);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        printf(BCYN "sqlite3_prepare returned: " BRED "%d => %s\n" reset , rc, sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return -1;
    }
```

this code outputs

```
sqlite3_open returned:  0
sqlite3_prepare returned: 1 => no such table: meta
```

Comment: [This question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82875/how-can-i-list-the-tables-in-a-sqlite-database-file-that-was-opened-with-attach)